# EF Core 3.0 1:0 relationship with fluent

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, fluent, ef-core-3.1

EF Core 3.0... I can't find a precise answer for this completely normal mapping.
Principal to Dependent with no back pointer to Principal, 1:0 relationship, a Type Object / Lookup table set up.  The problem is that the Object Key Name "RunId" is different than the EFCore generated key name "ServiceRunId"

**How can I use Fluent API to replace the [ForeignKey("aServiceRun")] annotation?**

This is my current Fluent set up, but I don't know where to put the ForeignKey mapping.

aBuilder.Entity<ServiceRun>().HasKey(new string[] { "RunId "});

aBuilder.Entity<Service>().HasOne(s => s.aServiceRun);

---

```
Class Service {        
  public int ServiceId {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("aServiceRun")]
  public int RunId { get; set; }

  public virtual ServiceRun aServiceRun { get; set; }
}

Class ServiceRun {
  public int RunId { get; set; }

  public string description {get ;set; }
}
```

Tables:

```
Service {
  ServiceId int

  RunId int
}

SerivceRun {
  RunId int

  Description string
}
```

Comment: Navigation properties doesn't matter, if `Service` contains a FK, then it cannot be the principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use Fluent API to replace the `[ForeignKey("aServiceRun")]` annotation?

You are seeking for [HasForeignKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencecollectionbuilder-2.hasforeignkey?view=efcore-3.1) fluent API. But in order to get access to it (and other relationship configuration APIs), you need to define the relationship by using `Has{One|Many}` followed by `With{One|Many}`. For [one-to-one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one) relationships you also need to provide the generic type argument to `HasForeignKey`:

> When configuring the relationship with the Fluent API, you use the `HasOne` and `WithOne` methods.
>
> When configuring the foreign key you need to specify the dependent entity type - notice the generic parameter provided to `HasForeignKey` in the listing below. In a one-to-many relationship it is clear that the entity with the reference navigation is the dependent and the one with the collection is the principal. But this is not so in a one-to-one relationship - hence the need to explicitly define it.

Note that the entity containing the FK is always the **dependent**, so with your model the `ServiceRun` is the principal, `Service` is the dependent, and the fluent configuration is a follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
    .HasOne(s => s.aServiceRun) // navigation property
    .WithOne() // no navigation property
    .HasForeignKey<Service>(s => s.RunId); // foreign key
```

Comment: Next step... What if the database field is ServiceRun.ID not RunId? Creating a different name to key off.
 
I have tried specifying the ServiceRun.HasKey(new string[] {"ID"}) but this did not create the mapping.

Comment: It's like any property which has different column name in the table, e.g. `modelBuilder.Entity<Service>().Property(s => s.RunId).HasColumnName("ID")`

Comment: I get Invalid column name 'ServiceRunTypeId1' It seems to be auto generating the field.

`modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceRunType>()
     .ToTable("ServiceRunType", schema: "load")
     .HasKey(new string[] { "Id" });
  modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
     .ToTable("Service", schema: "load")
     .HasKey(new string[] { "Id" });
  modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
      .Property("ServiceRunTypeId")
      .HasColumnName("TypeId");

  modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
      .HasOne(s => s.ServiceRunType)
      .WithOne()
      .HasForeignKey<Service>(s => s.ServiceRunTypeId);`

Comment: I don't know why the backticks didn't work for the code.

Comment: It's hard to follow through comments, and speaking about model (`ServiceRunType`) not shown here. Consider posting separate question with `Service` and `ServiceRun` classes + fluent configuration causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer to the above problem - I had a back-pointing list on my ServiceRun object that was not configured or ignored. I decided to leave this here as another example. Perhaps it will provide some worth to someone.

This is a 1:0 from Service to ServiceRunType where table names and property/field names don't match perfectly.

**Tables**

```
ServiceRun { //Does not match object name
int Id, 
string Desc
}
Service {
int Id, 
int RunId //Does not match object
}
```

**Objects**

```
Class ServiceRunType{  //Does not match table name
public int Id {get; set;} 
public String Desc {get; set;}
}
Class Service{
public int Id {get; set;} 
public int RunTypeId {get; set;} //Does not match table
public virtual ServiceRunType aServiceRunType { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent Code**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceRunType>()
.ToTable("ServiceRun", schema: "load")
.HasKey(new string[] { "Id" });
modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
.ToTable("Service", schema: "load") //Had to specify schema
.HasKey(new string[] { "Id" });
modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
.Property("RunTypeId")
.HasColumnName("RunId");
modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
.HasOne(s => s.aServiceRunType)
.WithOne()
.HasForeignKey<Service>(s => s.RunTypeId);
```